# SQL Select Query, Beginner

Tags: sql

I have this:

```
SELECT 
    IPAddress,
    URLMethod,
    COUNT(URLMETHOD) as Occurrence
FROM 
    accesslog2
WHERE 
    URLMethod LIKE '%login%'
GROUP BY 
    IPAddress, URLMethod
```

My problem is: I need the `IPaddresses` to only show up once but currently they show up duplicate times in the output.

I am writing a SQL `SELECT` query that lists each IP address and the number of times each IP address has an associated `URLMethod` that includes the word “login”. Each IP address value should only be listed once in the output.

Comment: Please post (by using [Edit]) some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Either your IP Addresses are not an exact match or you have different strings in URL Methods which are causing duplicate results since `GROUP BY` is unable to therefore group them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably remove the URLMethod from the results list, if you want IPAddress to show up only once.

```
SELECT 
    IPAddress,
    COUNT(URLMETHOD) as Occurrence
FROM 
    accesslog2
WHERE 
    URLMethod LIKE '%login%'
GROUP BY 
    IPAddress
```

Comment: No problem! I'd appreciate you "Accepting" my answer if it helped. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove URLMethod from the select and from the group by and you should be good to go.